# web scraping data from HTML table with no tag attributes

Tags: tags, attributes, urllib, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap data for Billboards top 100 from 1995 to 2015. Following is a sample link to the URL:
http://www.umdmusic.com/default.asp?Lang=English&Chart=E&ChDay=20&ChMonth=12&ChYear=2014&ChBand=&ChSong=E
I am using bs4 and urllib to convert the page to txt and then extract the tags using `find_all()`. I was able to extract the albums using following code:`table_data = bsObj.findAll('b')`.
However when I am trying to extract the statistics, I am not sure how can I extract as the `<td>` tag has no attribute:

[image]

Can anyone explain how can I extract the statistics which don't have attributes for the umdmusic website?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. The highlighted TD in the screenshot has 2 attributes, so what do you mean by "no attribute"?

Comment: as I say attribute, i mean a class or id attribute. This particular UMD website does not have the class or id for its tags. Hence it was a problem. However, i realized that going more in depth solved the problem.

I used the <b> tag to find the artists and then used list comprehension to download it. Thanks anyway for attending the question.

Comment: @MrLister, when i said no attributes, i meant the class or id